# How to split a string using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, split

I have a string which looks like this :

```
Birds(Parrort, cockatoo, Sparrow, KingFisher, Peacock), Big Dogs, Big Cats, Reptiles(Crocodile)
```

I want to split this string each part of the string like which looks like this

```
Birds(Parrort, cockatoo, Sparrow, KingFisher, Peacock)
Big Dogs
Big Cats
Reptiles(Crocodile)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will work.

Regex: `[A-Za-z\s]+(?:\([A-Za-z]+(?:\s*\,\s*[a-zA-Z]+)*\))?`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XDyd2j/1)

Comment: but if the string has space it treats every word separately:  ``Birds(Parrort, cockatoo, Sparrow, KingFisher, Peacock),Big Dogs, Big Cats, Reptiles(Crocodile)`;` `` the result is like this `"Birds(Parrort, cockatoo, Sparrow, KingFisher, Peacock)"
`undefined
"Birds(Parrort, cockatoo, Sparrow, KingFisher, Peacock)"
"Big"
"Dogs"
"Big"
"Cats"
"Reptiles(Crocodile)"``

Comment: Can you give me an example? so that i can modify my regex

Comment: `undefined
"Birds(Parrort, cockatoo, Sparrow, KingFisher, Peacock)"
"Big"
"Dogs"
"Big"
"Cats"
"Reptiles(Crocodile)"` Big Dogs and Big Cats is one word but it treats is separately ! and first element is undefined for some reason

Comment: This is a different question. Okay let me check for it

Comment: Can you change you post with new question?

Comment: Thanks !! Basically there r three parts in a string first and last with parent and the middle one are individual. `Birds(Parrort, cockatoo, Sparrow, KingFisher, Peacock), Big Dogs, Big Cats, Reptiles(Crocodile)`;``

Comment: Thanks Perfect!! You saved a lot of time have been struggling for hours!

Comment: @sam Welcome.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try another way to do it:

Change the string to :

```
Birds(Parrort, cockatoo, Sparrow, KingFisher, Peacock)|Dogs|Cats|Reptiles(Crocodile)
```

use:

```
var str = "Birds(Parrort, cockatoo, Sparrow, KingFisher, Peacock)|Dogs|Cats|Reptiles(Crocodile)";
var res = str.split("|");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var str = 'Birds(Parrort, cockatoo, Sparrow, KingFisher, Peacock),Dogs, Cats, Reptiles(Crocodile)';
    var array = str.split(", (?![^(]*\\))");
    console.log(array);
```